# GUI won't start automatically Raspbian Pixel

Tags: boot-issues, gui, pixel, startx

I have a triple boot Raspberry, and after an update of Raspbian, the gui won't start, when boot option in `raspi-config` is on Desktop I get Splashscreen of Raspbian Pixel and after this I get a black screen with terminal cursor, but I can't tape any command, I tried alt+ctrl+F4 but the cursor still blink and nothing happens.

Note that when boot option is defined on terminal command, and I launch `sudo startx` the gui start well, the problem is when I want it to start automatically.

Comment: I had this same problem and I found that it was because of a poor power supply.

Comment: I think you're right the problem was back just few days after everything was Ok, I didn't found a good power supply, I use a 5V 1.5A which is not enough for the raspberry pi 3. But why when I lunch startx from terminal I can use the gui without any problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a problem with tightVNC after removing it now the desktop starts properly

Edit: after few days I got the problem back.

Comment: If you haven't sourced a 3A power supply yet, I'd suggest getting on that pronto.  I've had all sorts of problems with the Pi3 and lesser power supplies. (runs great for a while, and eventually failing with a corrupted SD card etc)